# How to fetch basic data of friends in facebook integration android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-permissions

I am integrating facebook sdk in android.
Currently I completed with

- Login
- Post message on wall
- User information
- user friend list

Now I want users friends basic information like (Name, email,picture,birthday,gender, location etc)..

I have friend list and now on list item click i want friends basic detail.

Please help me for this...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You'll get it in the same you you got the details of the user. Just like this-

```
/<friend-id>?fields=....
```

Of course, you need to ask for the permissions to get some of the details. List of permissions for fetching the friends data(other than the basic details)-

[image]

Another thing- there's no way you can fetch the friends **email**.